# How to measure a SUM of any value for each week for the current month filtered

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I have a visual that I need to calculate the total volumes of sales, I have linked this table of volumes with another table that contains month and week numbers.

I'm having trouble writing a measure that calculates the volume of sales in the first week of the month, then another measure for the second week, the third, and onwards.

I want to filter the month of reference, and show me the total of sales for the respective first week, second week, third, etc...

I tried to use the measure weeknumber = MIN(), weeknumber = MIN()+1, weeknumber= MIN()+2 ,but it seems the measure don't accept for me to add number with the MIN formula,

Anyone has an idea of how can I solve this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: is it possible to share the .pbix file with data so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1**. add [Month] [Week] column into sales table, calculate [sales volume] measure for next step:

> I have linked this table of volumes with another table that contains
> month and week numbers

based on your description, i think can use RELATED formula but should make sure you have created one-multiple relationship between two tables and the direction should be from another table to sales table:

*columns:*

```
Month=related('another table',[Month])
Week=related('another table',[Week])
```

*measure:*

```
Sales volume = sum('Table'[Sales])
```

**Step2**. create a new table to summarize sales volume of each week:

```
New table = 
summarize('Table','Table'[Month],'Table'[Week],
"sales volume",[Sales volume])
```

**Step3**. calculate week numbers per month with add new column [week no. per month] into New table:

```
Week NO. per Month = 
rankx(filter('New table',[Month]=earlier('New table'[Month])),
[Week],[Week],asc)
```

[image]

**Step4**. create any visuals you want:

[image]

Comment: Sia, your answer is well developed, thank you very much! I'm afraid to ask, but if I'm working in a Calendar Table (day is primary key), and I have column Month as numbers and column Week as numbers, how could I rank the week number, just as you mentioned in Step 3 on this kind of table?

Comment: Try this formula:  Week NO. per Month = 
RANKX(FILTER(SUMMARIZE('Calendar',[Month],[WEEK]),[Month]=EARLIER('Calendar'[Month])),
[Week],[Week],asc)